# Colab - Save model/ history after TPU training

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tpu

I'm using the TPU provided by Colab and the training works well. But there are some problems when I use callbacks trying to save the model and training loss.

Initially, I mount my drive, and passed the path, ie `"/content/drive/MyDrive/records/"`, and there's no error returned. But then I found out nothing was saved.

An example would be like this:

```
csv_logger = CSVLogger("/content/drive/MyDrive/records/model_history_log_TPU.csv", append=True)
```

And nothing happened.

Then, I tried to save them in Google Cloud Storage, so I passed the path as `gs://my-bucket/records/`, but the error retuns:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So, my question is, what is the correct way to save those data?

Comment: Could you share which tutorial you have used? How did you mount the GDrive? Did you created the GCS bucket before you try to do anything? In this [tutorial](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/tpu.ipynb#scrollTo=kIC5KKcJOB_A), you can see that in order to save a Keras model the `model.save()` is used. Have you used a similar method to save yours? Could you share this piece of your code?

Comment: @PjoterS Thanks for replying. I used the same tutorial you shared. And yes I have created my own bucket to store data. 
 I wrote `from google.colab import drive` and `drive.mount('/content/drive')` to mount GDrive. 
I used `model.save_weights("weights.h5")`, and it's incredibly slow.

Comment: I also have a callback that saves the model at the end of every epoch

Comment: Could you also share piece of code where you are saving your model and the callbacks. In addition, could you tell if predictions work as expected?

Comment: Please refer to the other question I asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67419887/extremely-slow-when-saving-model-on-colab-tpu?noredirect=1#comment119178225_67419887. And I'm not really sure it  prediction works. Since I have trouble on both validation and saving models...